# Работа с ms sql 2012 в ms sql server management 2017

Tags: sql-server

Здравствуйте. Есть необходимость работы с различными версиями ms sql server (2012,2017) на одном ПК.

Будут ли они совместимы друг с другом?

И получится ли работать с экземпляром ms sql server 2012 в  ms sql server management 2017 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, SSMS самостоятельный продукт, с ее помощью вы можете подключиться к любой младшей версии SQL Server, но Microsoft предупреждает, что могут быть фунции которые не поддерживаются или не полностью поддерживаются в новой SSMS для старых продутов вроде 2000 или 2005 сервера.

Comment: я бы не был уверен что из SSMS2012 получится подключиться в SQL Server 2017 с использованием полной функциональности. В обратную сторону без проблем. по крайней мере 2008я студия не работала с 12м сервером.

Comment: ну в данном случае обратная ситуация, но спасибо за комментарий)

Comment: ну вы ж написали что "к любой", а по факту речь про более младшие а не любые вообще :)

Comment: внес исправление ;)